# How to select contact based on customer drop down list in sharepoint designer 2013 for list from?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to display contact list based on customer drop down selected customer in SP2013 designer.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer is a tool that you use to build the page that is served to the user. It is not the interface the end user sees. If you want to show a dropdown with choices, use a choice field. Or use a lookup field to another list. This has nothing to do with SharePoint Designer as the tool that manipulates the page view.